# WinForms MenuItems syntax in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, menuitem

I'm trying to code a basic Windows Form. I've got the code below so far. Visual Studio doesn't recognize any of the lines like this one `MainMenu.MenuItems.Add(itemFile);`. Any time I've used MenuItems, the program doesn't understand and gives me an error. I've checked a bunch of sites and tutorials and they all use this kind of syntax so I feel like I've made an error somewhere.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Form
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MenuStrip MainMenu = new MenuStrip();
            this.MainMenuStrip = MainMenu;

            ToolStripMenuItem itemFile = new ToolStripMenuItem("&File");
            ToolStripMenuItem itemNew = new ToolStripMenuItem("&New");

            MainMenu.MenuItems.Add(itemFile);
            itemFile.MenuItems.Add(itemNew);

            ToolStripMenuItem itemFolder = new ToolStripMenuItem("&Folder");
            itemNew.MenuItems.Add(itemFolder);

            MainMenu.MenuItems.Add("Save &As");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The code fatally mixes the legacy .NET 1.0 MainMenu and .NET 2.0 MenuStrip classes.  Use `Items` instead.  And do consider using the designer to get this right.

Comment: It's simply avoided changing this: `MenuStrip MainMenu = new MenuStrip();` to this: `var mainMenu = new MenuStrip();`. Now `mainMenu` is declared as a Local Variable (camelCase), so it's quite harder to use a name that conflicts with existing classes, which have an initial uppercase letter (Pascal Case). Then you can better identify what the problem is. -- You can enforce these styles using the `Options` of the IDE (`Text Editor -> C# -> Code style -> Naming`). Also check the `General` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans said, you missed `MainMenu` class and `MenuStrip` class in the winform.

If you want to use `MenuStrip`, you can refer to the following code to create a menu.

```
        MenuStrip MainMenu = new MenuStrip();
        this.MainMenuStrip = MainMenu;
        ToolStripMenuItem itemFile = new ToolStripMenuItem("&File");
        ToolStripMenuItem itemNew = new ToolStripMenuItem("&New");
        MainMenu.Items.Add(itemFile);
        itemFile.DropDownItems.Add(itemNew);
        ToolStripMenuItem itemFolder = new ToolStripMenuItem("&Folder");
        itemNew.DropDownItems.Add(itemFolder);
        ToolStripMenuItem itemSave = new ToolStripMenuItem("Save &As");
        MainMenu.Items.Add(itemSave);
        ToolStripMenuItem itempc = new ToolStripMenuItem("&This PC");
        itemSave.DropDownItems.Add(itempc);
        ToolStripMenuItem itemC = new ToolStripMenuItem("&C Disk");
        ToolStripMenuItem itemD = new ToolStripMenuItem("&D Disk");
        ToolStripMenuItem itemE = new ToolStripMenuItem("&E Disk");
        itempc.DropDownItems.Add(itemC);
        itempc.DropDownItems.Add(itemD);
        itempc.DropDownItems.Add(itemE);

        Controls.Add(MainMenu);
```

Like this:

[image]

If you want to use `MainMenu`, here is a code example you can refer to.

```
        MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
        MenuItem File = mainMenu.MenuItems.Add("&File");
        File.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("&New"));
        File.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("&Open"));
        File.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("&Exit"));
        this.Menu = mainMenu;
        MenuItem About = mainMenu.MenuItems.Add("&About");
        About.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("&About"));
        this.Menu = mainMenu;
        mainMenu.GetForm().BackColor = Color.White;
```

Result:

[image]